# Maximum call stack size exceeded when split

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, stack-overflow

Trying to duplicate [Agar](https://agar.io)'s splitting function but when I call it, the maximum call stack size is exceeded. ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khanfused/6t07o0qv/4/)) [note: don't click the canvas because that will trigger the split function)

This is the snippet that causes the overflow:

```
this.cells.push({
    coords: {
        x: this.cells[i].coords.x + 50,
        y: this.cells[i].coords.y
    },
    mass: this.mass,
    velocity: {
        x: this.cells[i].velocity.x,
        y: this.cells[i].velocity.y
    },
    hue: this.cells[i].hue
});
```

It *only* happens when I push something into this.cells. Modifying this.cells in any other way or pushing into other arrays or anything else works fine. Note that pushing into this.cells outside of the for loop it's currently in works fine. (doesn't produce desired effect but doesn't cause an overflow like the current one does)

Why does it cause an overflow and how would I prevent it and get the split function to work properly?

Comment: Don't add things to an `array` in that for loop if you're using `for (var i = 0; i < this.cells.length; i++)` to loop. Each time you add item, length becomes one more, and it never ends. You should use `var len = this.cells.length` to keep the init value, and use `for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)` to loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this line in `split`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.cells.length; i++)
```

It'll get the newest `length` of `cell` in each iteration, and as you put something into it, the `i` can never exceed the length, so it just loop forever.

Use:

```
// Get the init value of the length, 
// so push something into this.cells won't make it unable to end.
var length = this.cells.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
```

to make a temp copy of length to prevent this.
or

```
// Start at the end of the array, if the order is not a concern.
for (var i =  this.cells.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Start the iteration at end of array.

By the way, to display correct split result,

```
this.cells.push({
    coords: {
        x: this.cells[i].coords.x + 50,
        y: this.cells[i].coords.y
    },
    mass: this.mass,
    velocity: {
        x: this.cells[i].velocity.x,
        y: this.cells[i].velocity.y
    },
    hue: this.cells[i].hue
});
```

Should change to

```
this.cells.push({
    coords: {
        x: this.cells[i].coords.x + 50,
        y: this.cells[i].coords.y
    },

    // this.mass is undefined, I believe you intend to get the current cell's mass here.
    mass: this.cells[i].mass,

    velocity: {
        x: this.cells[i].velocity.x,
        y: this.cells[i].velocity.y
    },
    hue: this.cells[i].hue
});
```

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6t07o0qv/9/), [reverse ver.](https://jsfiddle.net/6t07o0qv/8/)